# unable to create cluster usin GCP Kubernetes engine page throws error "Failed to load"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

On using google console for creating a cluster the page loads says "Failed to Load"

Also when I try using gcloud sdk to create a cluster it throws error

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/xxxxxxx/global/networks/defualt

While looking at the permisssion for mgy IAM user I have the role for owner and compute engine as well.

Currently unable to use GCP Kubernetes engine

Comment: Do you still have this problem? It more looks like temporary authorization issue. Have you tried to create new project and create GKE cluster there? Have you tried to use another browser?

Comment: This issue is fixed by enabling GKE using glcoud command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bikash Kumar Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10240105/bikash-kumar-sharma), the issue was solved by enabling GKE using gcloud command.